# Spring Boot elastic Search Query with constraint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I am pretty new to this elastic search and spring boot world, I have been trying to search for this solution from past 2-3 days, sadly I was unable to (probably because I am new to this).

I have 3 columns inside elastic search, the first being the Id, second being name (upon which I am creating autocomplete API), and the third field with set of numbers called numbers. My use case is that for a particular number in the 3rd column, I want autocomplete suggestions from 2nd column.

This I have implemented with this code and it works: `repo.findByNumbersAndName(String, String)`

But this does not allow me to set fuzziness, wildcardquery and other search parameter, so I tried using QueryBuilders but I am not successful in building logic (I basically tried using BooleanQueryBuilder), So if anyone can help me on this it would be really helpful!!

Spring boot version - 2.4.2

Thanks in advance.

Edit1:-

To give better understanding of my use case, let say this is what I have stored in elastic Search

```
Id | Name   | Numbers |
-----------------------
a1 | ashwin | 1       |
a2 | Ram    | 3       |
a3 | Kumar  | 2       |
a4 | Some   | 2       |
a5 | body   | 1       |
a6 | any    | 3       |
a7 | one    | 4       |
a8 | ashwin | 2       |
```

Now I should have the control to specify my query saying that for this number (let's say 1), what are the autocomplete possibilities if input for autocomplete "a". Then the program should search for possibilities that have number "1" in the numbers column only, so in this scenario there is only one output that is "ashwin".

Edit2:-

I believe my configuration and query method is same as what you have done, I will just paste what I have done. One update is that though the Number field in database contains Integers but they are stored as String datatype, would that make any difference while term Query?

This is my elastic-analyzer.json

```
{

  "analysis": {
    "filter": {
      "autocomplete_filter": {
        "type": "edge_ngram",
        "min_gram": 3,
        "max_gram": 30
      }
    },
    "analyzer": {
      "autocomplete_search": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "stop"
          
        ]
      },
      "autocomplete_index": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "autocomplete_filter",
          "stop"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using this to generate a Query: -

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        
        .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("Number", number))
        .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("Name", search_word));
```

The above generates the query in this format -

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "term" : {
          "Number" : {
            "value" : "1",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match" : {
          "Name" : {
            "query" : "ash",
            "operator" : "OR",
            "prefix_length" : 0,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
            "lenient" : false,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
```

This is producing empty array, not able to understand why? The below I feel is equivalent of properties that you had mentioned in Index Mapping

```
@Id
@Field(type = FieldType.Text)
private String Id;

@Field(type = FieldType.Text, analyzer = "autocomplete_index", searchAnalyzer = "autocomplete_search")
private String Name;

@Field(type = FieldType.Text)
private String Number;
```

Thanks @ESCoder

Edit 3:-

I stumbled upon this with help from @ESCoder as well,

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        
        .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("Number", search_number).boost(1f).operator(Operator.AND))
        .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("Name", keyword).boost(0.4f));
```

This is the Query spring generated for ElasticSearch,

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "match" : {
          "Number" : {
            "query" : "1",
            "operator" : "AND",
            "prefix_length" : 0,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
            "lenient" : false,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match" : {
          "Name" : {
            "query" : "ash",
            "operator" : "OR",
            "fuzziness" : "1",
            "prefix_length" : 0,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
            "lenient" : false,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
            "boost" : 0.4
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 4
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"
      },
      "Id": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "Numbers": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "Name": "ashwin",
  "Id": "a1",
  "Numbers": 1
}
{
  "Name": "ashwin",
  "Id": "a1",
  "Numbers": 2
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "Name": "a"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "Numbers": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66923434",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.2630212,
        "_source": {
          "Name": "ashwin",
          "Id": "a1",
          "Numbers": 1
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

With your current index mapping setting, the following tokens are generated for `ashwin`

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
  "text" : "ashwin"
}
```

Tokens are:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "ash",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "ashw",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "ashwi",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "ashwin",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

**You need to modify your index mapping, instead of `"min_gram": 3` you need to change it to `"min_gram": 1`.**

**Update 2:**

You need to even change `"search_analyzer"` to `standard`.

Comment: Hi @ESCoder, thanks for quick reply!! I have updated my answer, please do let me know if there is anything wrong in my code as I didn't find any difference what I had implemented before and what you have sent now. THanks once again!

Comment: @ashwinramkumar please go through the updated part of the answer and let me know if this resolves your issue?

Comment: If my query for search is "ash" (3 letter word) where Number == "1", it should be able to pick it up even when ngram=3 (meaning "ash" is present as a token), but I am still getting an empty list when I run the result.Thanks!!

Comment: @ashwinramkumar You need to set `"search_analyzer": "standard"`. Please go through the index mapping as shown in the answer above. Now when you search for `ash`, you will get the required result. Let me know if this works for you :-)

Comment: No it didn't work but I found a solution in trial and Error, updating the answer now

Comment: Yep.. Added the upvote!! Thanks for the help, once again